# Positioning Items in Unordered List

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, floating

I have a [demo](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/). I want to align red arrows left like in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Rkj.jpg). But i couldn't figure out how do i do. By the way red arrows coming from javascript side.

```
  function ytplayer_render_playlist( )
  {
    var arrOfListNodes = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementById('mylist').childNodes, function (e) {return e.tagName === 'LI';});
    for ( var i = 0; i < ytplayer_playlist.length; i++ )
    {   
      var img = document.createElement( "img" );
      img.src = "track_arrow.gif";
      var a = document.createElement( "a" );
      a.href = "#ytplayer";
      a.onclick = (
        function( j )
        {
          return function( )
          {
            ytplayer_playitem = j;
            ytplayer_playlazy( 0 );
          };
        }
      )( i );
      a.appendChild( img );
      arrOfListNodes[i].insertBefore(a, arrOfListNodes[i].firstChild);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's because the div is floated left. Just add a `float:left` to the `<a>` element that you create.

Answer (score 2):

**Define** `.ikinciSol ul li a` `float:left;`

In your css as like this

```
.ikinciSol ul li a{
float:left;
}
```

Results

[image]

Comment: @Rohit, place of dash is changed. Also item inside song class is little slipped over.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an alternative way, using the `::before` selector.

Like so:

```
artist_track::before {
  background-image: url(http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/track_arrow.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: your approach is appropriate in this situation. because img tag will request every time when img tag declare in html. Using css only once the request goes to server. you answer is right.

Comment: Then, how can i make this background image clickable by javascript?